# Why doesn't julia broadcasting work when deals with more than one array?

Tags: julia

I have defined two structs and a function like this

```
struct A
    x::Float64
end

struct B
    y::Float64
end

f(a::A, b::B) = a.x*sin(b.y)
f.([A(0.1), A(0.2)], [B(1.), B(2.), B(3.)])
```

But f returns this error:

> DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")

How can I solve this error? I expect an array with 6 elements as the function output.

Comment: Perhaps this visual guide would be helpful: https://julia.guide/broadcasting

Comment: No problem. I'm just a beginner programmer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your first argument is a 2-element `Vector`, and a second argument is 3-element `Vector`.

If you e.g. make the first argument a 1x2 `Matrix`, then all works fine:

```
julia> f.([A(0.1) A(0.2)], [B(1.), B(2.), B(3.)])
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0841471  0.168294
 0.0909297  0.181859
 0.014112   0.028224
```

(note that the missing or 1-length dimensions get automatically broadcasted)

Note that you could also broadcast calls to `A` and `B` constructors:

```
f.(A.([0.1 0.2]), B.(1.:3.))
```

Comment: Sir! You answered my post so fast!

Answer (score 1):

The arrays have to have compatible dimensions - either identical in size and shape (local operations), or they span a larger vector space where each has singleton dimensions where the others have non-singleton dimensions, e.g.  as an operation on the dimensions, the .* operator will cause the mapping

```
(1 x 1 x n) .* (p x q x 1)  => p x q x n
```

Comment: additionally, as I have commented above, a missing dimension is treated as a singleton dimension e.g. `(1 x 1 x n) .* (p x q)  => p x q x n`.